# Cannot get Pulsar proxy HTTP and binary URLs

Tags: bash, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube, apache-pulsar

I am currently working on installing Pulsar inside of Minikube. The installation seems to be going okay, however at the end when I try to get the HTTP proxy URL and binary proxy URL... I get an error message that I am not specifying a valid service:

```
xyz-MBP:pulsar xyz$ kubectl get services -n pulsar | grep pulsar-mini-proxy
pulsar-mini-proxy            LoadBalancer   10.107.193.52    <pending>     80:31241/TCP,6650:32025/TCP           8h
xyz-MBP:pulsar xyz$ minikube service pulsar-mini-proxy -n pulsar –-url

❌  Exiting due to MK_USAGE: You must specify a service name
```

Is there something I am doing wrong in the command I am using to display the services? Why doesn't the proxy show up as a service?

Here is what I did to get Pulsar installed into Minikube:

```
#!/bin/bash

# this script assumes that the pre-requisites have been
# installed, and that you just need to create a minikube
# cluster and then deploy pulsar to it

# startup a minikube kubernetes cluster
minikube start --memory=8192 --cpus=4 --kubernetes-version=v1.19.0

# point kubectl towards minikube
kubectl config use-context minikube

# install the pulsar helm chart
./pulsar-helm-chart/scripts/pulsar/prepare_helm_release.sh --create-namespace --namespace pulsar --release pulsar-mini

# install pulsar using the helm chart
helm install --set initialize=true --values pulsar-helm-chart/examples/values-minikube.yaml -n pulsar pulsar-mini apache/pulsar

# wait and then show what is going on
sleep 1m
kubectl get all

# need to wait or else the pods wont display
sleep 5m

# display the pods
kubectl get pods -n pulsar -o name
```

Just another update, it doesn't look like anything gets a URL assigned to it from the helm install:

```
xyz-MBP:pulsar xyz$ minikube service list
|-------------|----------------------------|--------------|-----|
|  NAMESPACE  |            NAME            | TARGET PORT  | URL |
|-------------|----------------------------|--------------|-----|
| default     | kubernetes                 | No node port |
| kube-system | kube-dns                   | No node port |
| pulsar      | pulsar-mini-bookie         | No node port |
| pulsar      | pulsar-mini-broker         | No node port |
| pulsar      | pulsar-mini-grafana        | server/3000  |     |
| pulsar      | pulsar-mini-prometheus     | No node port |
| pulsar      | pulsar-mini-proxy          | http/80      |     |
|             |                            | pulsar/6650  |     |
| pulsar      | pulsar-mini-pulsar-manager | server/9527  |     |
| pulsar      | pulsar-mini-toolset        | No node port |
| pulsar      | pulsar-mini-zookeeper      | No node port |
|-------------|----------------------------|--------------|-----|
```

Comment: I don't use minikube, but when using kind, this helps when LoadBalancer is needed: https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/loadbalancer/ . I believe that MetalLB also works with Minikube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar kind of setup and I installed the [helm](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/#from-apt-debianubuntu) before installing the [pulsar](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/kubernetes-helm/) in the minikube. After I executed these two commands and got the urls.

$ kubectl -n pulsar get services

$ minikube service -n pulsar pulsar-mini-proxy

[image]

Comment: Let me give that a try and I will get back to you.

Comment: This worked for me, i'm not really sure why though.